# Why does this not make a good looking square?

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

Ok, first of all I totally agree that "TheNewBoston" tutorials are very... wrong at times. However that is what I was following to try to make a cube in OpenGL on android.

Anyways, I can't say that I have found great material on OpenGL to be honest. I have read through OpenGL Superbible... it was ok.

So here is the code that I have.

GLRenderer.java

```
package android.gem.opengltest;

import javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLConfig;
import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10;

import android.opengl.GLU;
import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView.Renderer;
import android.os.SystemClock;

public class GLRenderer implements Renderer {

    private GLCube cube;

    public GLRenderer() {
        cube = new GLCube();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_DITHER);
        gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT);

        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();
        GLU.gluLookAt(gl, 0, 0, -5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0);

        long time = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() % 4000L;
        float angle = .09f * ((int) time);

        gl.glRotatef(angle, 1, 1.5f, 2);

        cube.draw(gl);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        float ratio = (float) width / height;

        gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();
        gl.glFrustumf(-ratio, ratio, -1, 1, 1, 25);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig eglConfig) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        // START OF PERFORMANCE //
        gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_DITHER);
        gl.glHint(GL10.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL10.GL_FASTEST);
        // END OF PERFORMANCE //

        gl.glClearColor(.8f, 0, .2f, 1f);  // Red, Green, Blue, Alpha (0 - 1)
        gl.glClearDepthf(1f);
    }
```

}

GLCube.java

```
package android.gem.opengltest;

import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;
import java.nio.FloatBuffer;
import java.nio.ShortBuffer;

import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10;

public class GLCube {

    private float verticies[] = {
            1, 1, -1, // point 0 - topFrontRight
            1, -1, -1, // point 1 - bottomFrontRight
            -1, -1, -1, // point 2 - bottomFrontLeft
            -1, 1, -1, // point 3 - frontTopLeft
            1, 1, 1, // point 4 - topBackRight
            1, -1, 1, // point 5 - bottomBackRight
            -1, -1, 1, // point 6 - bottomBackLeft
            -1, 1, 1 // point 7 - frontBackLeft
    };

    private float rgbaValues[] = {
             1, 1, 0, 1,
             .25f, 0, .85f, 1,
             0, 1, 1, 1,
             1, 1, 0, 1,
             .25f, 0, .85f, 1,
             0, 1, 1, 1,
             .5f, .5f, .2f, 1,
             .3f, .3f, .3f, 1
    };

    private FloatBuffer vertBuff, colorBuff;

    private short[] pIndex = {  // Indicies
            3, 4, 0,  0, 4, 1,  3, 0, 1,
            3, 7, 4,  7, 6, 4,  7, 3, 6,
            3, 1, 2,  1, 6, 2,  6, 3, 2,
            1, 4, 5,  5, 6, 1,  6, 5, 4
    };

    private ShortBuffer pBuffer;

    public GLCube() {
        ByteBuffer bBuff = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(this.verticies.length * 4);
        bBuff.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        vertBuff = bBuff.asFloatBuffer();
        vertBuff.put(this.verticies);
        vertBuff.position(0);

        ByteBuffer pbBuff = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(this.pIndex.length * 2);
        pbBuff.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        pBuffer = pbBuff.asShortBuffer();
        pBuffer.put(pIndex);
        pBuffer.position(0);

        ByteBuffer cBuff = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(this.rgbaValues.length * 4);
        cBuff.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        colorBuff = cBuff.asFloatBuffer();
        colorBuff.put(rgbaValues);
        colorBuff.position(0);
    }

    public void draw(GL10 gl) {
        gl.glFrontFace(GL10.GL_CW); // Clock Wise
        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_CULL_FACE);  // Removes back end of cube
        gl.glCullFace(GL10.GL_BACK);
        gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_COLOR_ARRAY);

        gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, this.vertBuff);
        gl.glColorPointer(4, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, this.colorBuff);
        gl.glDrawElements(GL10.GL_TRIANGLES, this.pIndex.length, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, this.pBuffer);

        gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
        gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_CULL_FACE);
    }

}
```

I get a cube that looks like this...

[image]

What am I doing wrong? What should I do to make it look like an actual cube?

Also, if it helps all my code is at the following address: https://github.com/gemurdock/OpenGlTest/tree/alpha.0.1.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, this is a (*horribly deformed*) cube, **not** a square. Unless you look at it face-on it is never going to look like a "good square" :)

Your polygon face culling appears to be culling the wrong side of your cube faces. It still looks like a cube, just an inside out cube.

This is likely because you have overridden OpenGL's default front face winding direction (`GL_CCW`).

Comment: My bad, I tend to interchange square and cube. - Also, you were completely right. Thank you so much. Just wondering... why does it matter if you go CCW or CW? Would just researching Google on "Culling" be enough to learn?

Comment: CCW and CW are the scheme that OpenGL uses to identify the front and back of a face. Ordinarily faces do not have fronts or backs, they are just a filled collection of points. There are a couple of ways to identify the front and back, one would be to use a vector that is normal to the surface and another is simply to detect which direction the vertices are wound. GL choses the later for simplicity and speed. Many engines pre-process triangles on the CPU before submitting them to OpenGL using the triangle normal and a dot product to do early culling; so the two are not mutually exclusive.

Comment: This may be an interesting read if you're still curious how it works: http://www.sumantaguha.com/files/materials/chapter9.pdf

Comment: So is it always true that CW shows the back of a triangle? Or is that relative to something? - BTW, Chapter 9 of that book is super helpful... I am probably going to order that book.

Comment: No, it is relative to the camera and the order the vertices are drawn in. When rendering in right-handed vs. left-handed coordinate systems (which is the case if you migrate from Direct3D to OpenGL), polygon winding orientations are reversed. You could have fixed your problem in this question by using `GL_CCW` as the front-face or by leaving it the way it was, and simply reversing your index array.

Comment: That is very helpful, thank you again! Could not have gotten that without you.